# Dynamically passing ids using slim instead of erb in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

Hi I use slim in rails instead of erb.
I need to generate dynamic ids based on the id of the record passed to the view page. This is a part of my code:

```
 #clear_class_"#{activity.id}"
   - user = activity.user
 .row
   .col-xs-3.col-md-2.person_img
   = link_to (image_tag user.avatar.url :normal, alt: user.full_name, class: 'img img-responsive'),  user_path(user)
   ...
```

when I try using #clear_class_"#{activity.id}" the view is getting distorted. How can I make this division a dynamic one with my activity id appended to the division id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option, if you just want to use basic string interpolation, would be this:

```
div id="clear-class-#{activity.id}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
div id=dom_id(activity, 'clear_class')
```

Comment: Worked like charm.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also try if you simply want only the `id` of that activity:

```
div id=activity.id
```